# How do I find out which process is using a file when Process Explorer and Handle doesn't work?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, filesystems, lock

How do i find out which process is using this file? Windows 8.1.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\Teads>echo Hello > selenium.log
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

[image: Imgur]

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\Teads>"\Program Files (x86)"\handle selenium.log

Handle v4.0
Copyright (C) 1997-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

No matching handles found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to run in an elevated command shell as Administrator.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\Teads>"\Program Files (x86)"\handle selenium.log

Handle v4.0
Copyright (C) 1997-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

chrome.exe         pid: 9252   type: File            20: C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\Teads\selenium.log
```